# $\mathbb{Z}$ has finite index in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $d$ be a square-free integer. Does $\mathbb{Z}$ have finite or infinite index in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}\,]?$

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* As an additive group, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Then the index is infinite because $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Thank you!